# Al darle click en el boton desaparece los span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

tengo un problema, tengo una palabra que cuando carga la pagina cada letra tiene un color diferente use

> ```
> <style>
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 1) 
> {
>  color:#ff2222;
>  }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 2) 
> {
>  color:#22aa22;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 3) 
> {
>  color:#ffaa22;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 4) 
> {
>  color:#aa00aa;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 5) 
> {
>  color:#00aaa0;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 6) 
> {
>  color:#ff06d5;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 7) 
> {
>  color:#9f5522;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 8) 
> {
> color:#a10c97;
> }
> #word span:nth-child(9n + 9) 
> {
> color:#22ffcf;
> }
> </style>
> ```
>
> ```
>   $(function(){
>
>       $('#word').html(
>           $('#word').text().replace(/(\w)/g,'<span>$1</span>')
>       );
>   })
> ```

pero cuando le doy click en un botón para que me cambie la palabra se desaparece los span que me genera el script , pero necesito que se mantenga por decirlo así

> 

```
                <div class="centro">
                  <h1 id="word">

                    Click On Button

                </h1>
                </div>

                <div>
                  <form method="post" class="centro">
                    <input type="button" name="catg" value="New Word" class="centro w" onclick="boton()">
                  </form>
                </div>

          </div>
```

> ```
>  <script  type="text/javascript">
>   var boton = function() {
>    fetch('sqla.php')
>   .then(function(response) {
>  return response.text();
>    })
>     .then(function(body) {
>    document.querySelector('#word').innerHTML = body;
>    });
>    };
>
>   document.addEventListener('click', function() {
>    boton();
>   });
>   </script>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la palabra se colorea solo al iniciar la página, y al momento de asignarle un nuevo en document.querySelector('#word').innerHTML = body; no se coloreara por que la pagina ya está iniciada, te aconsejo hacer una función para colorear o bien un evento. Para un ejemplo trabaje con “Hola mundo” de manera estática y le puse un nombre a tu función colorear(); a esta la llamo una vez cargada la página y al entrar a var botón. Espero te ayude.

```js
if (document.addEventListener) {
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", colorear, false);
}
function colorear(){
      $('#word').html(
         $('#word').text().replace(/(\w)/g,'<span>$1</span>')
      );
 }
 
  var boton = function() {
   /*fetch('sqla.php')
  .then(function(response) {
 return response.text();
   })
    .then(function(body) {
   document.querySelector('#word').innerHTML = body;
   });*/
   
   let body="Hola Mundo";
   document.querySelector('#word').innerHTML = body;
   colorear();
   }

  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
   boton();
  });
```

```css
#word span:nth-child(9n + 1) 
{
 color:#ff2222;
 }
#word span:nth-child(9n + 2) 
{
 color:#22aa22;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 3) 
{
 color:#ffaa22;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 4) 
{
 color:#aa00aa;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 5) 
{
 color:#00aaa0;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 6) 
{
 color:#ff06d5;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 7) 
{
 color:#9f5522;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 8) 
{
color:#a10c97;
}
#word span:nth-child(9n + 9) 
{
color:#22ffcf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="centro">
 <h1 id="word"> Click On Button </h1>
</div>
<div>
 <form method="post" class="centro">
     <input type="button" name="catg" value="New Word" class="centro w" onclick="boton()">
   </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```